# Image Resize - Fixed width and height with padding even image is smaller

Tags: imageresizer

When i upload 100x100 image, i cant make it 120x120 with whitespace filled for those extra 20px.

If i upload 200x150, then 120x120 image is ok, filled whitespace.

This is my code.

```
var setting = new ResizeSettings
                       {
                           Width = 120,
                           Height = 120,
                           Format = "jpg"
                       };


 ImageBuilder.Current.Build(image, "desctination", setting, false, false);
```

Don`t know why, but i think i used this method successfully  in past.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This is explained in paragraph 2 of the [ImageResizer API Introduction page](http://imageresizing.net/docs/basics); use `&scale=canvas` or Scale = ScaleMode.UpscaleCanvas.

Comment: Heh, i visited that page maybe 50 times and i didn`t notice this! Thanks a lot!